# Updating foreign keys while inserting into new table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table A(id).

I need to

- create table B(id)
- add a foreign key to table A that references to B.id
- for every row in A, insert a row in B and update A.b_id with the newly inserted row in B

Is it possible to do it without adding a temporary column in B that refers to A?  The below does work, but I'd rather not have to make a temporary column.

```
alter table B add column ref_id integer references(A.id);
insert into B (ref_id) select id from A;
update A set b_id = B.id from B where B.ref_id = A.id;
alter table B drop column ref_id;
```

Comment: Is the question too confusing?

Comment: Your question does not make sense. What are you **really** trying to achieve?

Comment: That would work in this scenario, but I have 12 other tables that need to insert corresponding rows into A as well.

Comment: In this case, I have many tables that need to have a 'commentable' association.  I have a comments table that will have a commentable_id, and many tables that will have a commentable_id, and the commentable_id in the tables will refer to commentables.id (A.id, in this example).

Comment: But what if rows are added to the "base" tables later? You will need to re-run this statement over and over again (or add a trigger to each and every base table). Wouldn't it make more sense to only insert rows into the comments table once a comment is made?

Comment: Yes, you'd have a trigger on each base table to update the commentables table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that:

1) you're using postgresql 9.1

2) B.id is a serial (so actually an int with a default value of nextval('b_id_seq')

3) when inserting to B, you actually add other fields from A otherwise the insert is useless

...I think something like this would work:

```
with n as (select nextval('b_id_seq') as newbid,a.id as a_id  from a),
   l as (insert into b(id) select newbid from n returning id as b_id)
 update a set b_id=l.b_id from l,n where a.id=n.a_id and l.b_id=n.newbid;
```

Comment: Why 3 (the insert is useless if there's no other columns)?  Good thought on the CTE, I'll try that.

Comment: Considering the SQL `insert into B(ref_id)` and the goal being to get rid of ref_id, what columns would you insert into if there is no B.ref_id?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the future foreign key column, but without the constraint itself:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE A ADD b_id integer;
   ```
2. Fill the new column with values:

   ```
   WITH cte AS (
     SELECT
       id
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS b_ref
     FROM A
   )
   UPDATE A
   SET b_id = cte.b_ref
   FROM cte
   WHERE A.id = cte.id;
   ```
3. Create the other table:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE B (
     id integer CONSTRAINT PK_B PRIMARY KEY
   );
   ```
4. Add rows to the new table using the referencing column of the existing one:

   ```
   INSERT INTO B (id)
   SELECT b_id
   FROM A;
   ```
5. Add the `FOREIGN KEY` constraint:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE A
   ADD CONSTRAINT FK_A_B FOREIGN KEY (b_id) REFERENCES B (id);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

PostgeSQL dialect.

You might use an anonymous code block like this

```
do $$
    declare
        category_cursor cursor for select id from schema1.categories;
        r_category bigint;
        setting_id bigint;
    begin
        open category_cursor;
        loop fetch category_cursor into r_category;
        exit when not found;
        insert into schema2.setting(field)
        values ('field_value') returning id into setting_id;
        update schema1.categories set category_setting_id = setting_id 
        where category_id = r_category;
        end loop;
    end; $$
```

1. Let assume we have two tables first - categories, second - settings which must be applied to these categories.
2. First step - declare cursor(collect ids from categories), and variabels where we store temporary data
3. Loop cursor inserting values 'field_value' into settings
4. Store id in variable setting_id
5. Update table categories with setting_id

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. It would be very helpful for everyone of you could append an explanation on how your code works!